# Weighted average in T-SQL (like Excel's SUMPRODUCT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, statistics

I am looking for a way to derive a weighted average from two rows of data with the same number of columns, where the average is as follows (borrowing Excel notation):

```
(A1*B1)+(A2*B2)+...+(An*Bn)/SUM(A1:An)
```

The first part reflects the same functionality as Excel's SUMPRODUCT() function.

My catch is that I need to dynamically specify which row gets averaged with weights, and which row the weights come from, and a date range.

EDIT:  This is easier than I thought, because Excel was making me think I required some kind of pivot.  My solution so far is thus:

```
select sum(baseSeries.Actual * weightSeries.Actual) / sum(weightSeries.Actual)
from (
    select RecordDate , Actual 
    from CalcProductionRecords 
    where KPI = 'Weighty'
) baseSeries inner join (       
    select RecordDate , Actual 
    from CalcProductionRecords 
    where KPI = 'Tons Milled'   
) weightSeries on baseSeries.RecordDate = weightSeries.RecordDate
```

Comment: How does the date range come into it?  How many columns - a few or lots?  Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: @martin, just one column.  It used to be one per KPI, but that wasn't fun.  The date range is for a reporting period.

Comment: Is the above statement considered a CTE?  If not how could you turn that into a CTE?  Anyone?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I never considered it a CTE, but to novice me it looks like it could be used as one. I just can't tell you how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quassnoi's answer shows how to do the SumProduct, and using a WHERE clause would allow you to restrict by a Date field...

```
SELECT
   SUM([tbl].data * [tbl].weight) / SUM([tbl].weight)
FROM
   [tbl]
WHERE
   [tbl].date >= '2009 Jan 01'
   AND [tbl].date < '2010 Jan 01'
```

The more complex part is where you want to "dynamically specify" the what field is [data] and what field is [weight].  The short answer is that realistically you'd have to make use of Dynamic SQL.  Something along the lines of:
- Create a string template
- Replace all instances of [tbl].data with the appropriate data field
- Replace all instances of [tbl].weight with the appropriate weight field
- Execute the string

Dynamic SQL, however, carries it's own overhead.  Is the queries are relatively infrequent , or the execution time of the query itself is relatively long, this may not matter.  If they are common and short, however, you may notice that using dynamic sql introduces a noticable overhead.  (Not to mention being careful of SQL injection attacks, etc.)

**EDIT:**

In your lastest example you highlight three fields:

- RecordDate
- KPI
- Actual

When the [KPI] is "Weight Y", then [Actual] the Weighting Factor to use.
When the [KPI] is "Tons Milled", then [Actual] is the Data you want to aggregate.

Some questions I have are:

- Are there any other fields?
- Is there only ever ONE actual per date per KPI?

The reason I ask being that you want to ensure the JOIN you do is only ever 1:1.  (You don't want 5 Actuals joining with 5 Weights, giving 25 resultsing records)

Regardless, a slight simplification of your query is certainly possible...

```
SELECT
   SUM([baseSeries].Actual * [weightSeries].Actual) / SUM([weightSeries].Actual)
FROM
   CalcProductionRecords AS [baseSeries]
INNER JOIN
   CalcProductionRecords AS [weightSeries]
      ON [weightSeries].RecordDate = [baseSeries].RecordDate
--    AND [weightSeries].someOtherID = [baseSeries].someOtherID
WHERE
   [baseSeries].KPI = 'Tons Milled'
   AND [weightSeries].KPI = 'Weighty'
```

The commented out line only needed if you need additional predicates to ensure a 1:1 relationship between your data and the weights.

If you can't guarnatee just One value per date, and don't have any other fields to join on, you can modify your sub_query based version slightly...

```
SELECT
   SUM([baseSeries].Actual * [weightSeries].Actual) / SUM([weightSeries].Actual)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        RecordDate,
        SUM(Actual)
    FROM
        CalcProductionRecords
    WHERE
        KPI = 'Tons Milled'
    GROUP BY
        RecordDate
)
   AS [baseSeries]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        RecordDate,
        AVG(Actual)
    FROM
        CalcProductionRecords
    WHERE
        KPI = 'Weighty'
    GROUP BY
        RecordDate
)
   AS [weightSeries]
      ON [weightSeries].RecordDate = [baseSeries].RecordDate
```

This assumes the AVG of the weight is valid if there are multiple weights for the same day.

**EDIT :** Someone just voted for this so I thought I'd improve the final answer :)

```
SELECT
   SUM(Actual * Weight) / SUM(Weight)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        RecordDate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN KPI = 'Tons Milled' THEN Actual ELSE NULL END)   AS Actual,
        AVG(CASE WHEN KPI = 'Weighty'     THEN Actual ELSE NULL END)   AS Weight
    FROM
        CalcProductionRecords
    WHERE
        KPI IN ('Tons Milled', 'Weighty')
    GROUP BY
        RecordDate
)
   AS pivotAggregate
```

This avoids the JOIN and also only scans the table once.

It relies on the fact that `NULL` values are ignored when calculating the `AVG()`.

Comment: @Dems, seems I was seeing things as too complicated, because the dynamically supplied values are field values, not names, as I have amended above.

Comment: This code will fail in the case where weight sum = 0.

Comment: @TKBruin `1.` This is a TEN year old post. `2.` If there are no Weighty values, the aggregate will return NULL not 0. `3.` If all the Weighty values are 0, the aggregate will return 0, but then the data is faulty and should be corrected.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT  SUM(A * B) / SUM(A)
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: You are assuming the values come from two different columns.  They actually come from the same column in different sets of records.

Comment: Could you please post some sample data then?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand the problem then  try this

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
    declare @tbl table(A int, B int,recorddate datetime,KPI varchar(50))
    insert into @tbl 
        select 1,10 ,'21/01/2009', 'Weighty'union all 
        select 2,20,'10/01/2009', 'Tons Milled' union all
        select 3,30 ,'03/02/2009', 'xyz'union all 
        select 4,40 ,'10/01/2009', 'Weighty'union all
        select 5,50 ,'05/01/2009', 'Tons Milled'union all 
        select 6,60,'04/01/2009', 'abc' union all
        select 7,70 ,'05/01/2009', 'Weighty'union all 
        select 8,80,'09/01/2009', 'xyz' union all
        select 9,90 ,'05/01/2009', 'kws'    union all 
        select 10,100,'05/01/2009', 'Tons Milled'

    select SUM(t1.A*t2.A)/SUM(t2.A)Result  from  
                   (select RecordDate,A,B,KPI from @tbl)t1 
        inner join(select RecordDate,A,B,KPI from @tbl t)t2
        on t1.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate
        and t1.KPI = t2.KPI
```