# SQL SUMPRODUCT with a twist

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table WIDGET
    Columns Country, Contract, Price

Table WEIGHT
    Columns Contract, Weight
```

I am trying to do `SUMRPRODUCT(Contract, Weight)/SUM(Weight)` but for all values of `Country`. What I have tried is adapted from [Weighted average in T-SQL (like Excel's SUMPRODUCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698408/weighted-average-in-t-sql-like-excels-sumproduct) and looks like

```
SELECT 
    Country 
    SUM(widget.price * weight.weight) / SUM(weight.weight)
FROM
    Widget
        INNER JOIN
    Weight ON Widget.contract = Weight.contract
WHERE
    Weight.contract >= '2016-01-01'
    AND Weight.contract <= '2016-12-01'
```

The problem with this is that it calculates it for one value of `Country` but not for all of them. How can I get a list of `DISTINCT(Country)` and the `SUMPRODUCT()/SUM()` for the filtered contracts next to it?

Sample Data

```
+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
| widget_id | country | contract   | price |
+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
|         4 | CA      | 2016-01-01 | 16.00 |
|         5 | CA      | 2016-02-01 | 32.00 |
|         6 | CA      | 2016-03-01 | 64.00 |
|         1 | US      | 2016-01-01 | 32.00 |
|         2 | US      | 2016-02-01 | 64.00 |
|         3 | US      | 2016-03-01 | 96.00 |
+-----------+---------+------------+-------+

+-----------+------------+--------+
| weight_id | contract   | weight |
+-----------+------------+--------+
|         1 | 2016-01-01 |      1 |
|         2 | 2016-02-01 |      8 |
|         3 | 2016-03-01 |     64 |
+-----------+------------+--------+
```

Desired output

```
+---------+-----------+
| Country | Wtd Price |
+---------+-----------+
| CA      | 59.835616 |
| US      | 91.616438 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just should group by country like this

```
SELECT 
    Country 
    SUM(widget.price * weight.weight) / SUM(weight.weight)
FROM
    Widget
        INNER JOIN
    Weight ON Widget.contract = Weight.contract
WHERE
    Weight.contract >= '2016-01-01'
    AND Weight.contract <= '2016-12-01'
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thank you.