# Calculate A Weighted Average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, weighted-average

Suppose I have a table that contains a number of transactions but I'd like to weight them by the number of stores in that state, is there a SQL command I can use that calculates the weighted average and not just the average (AVG())?

```
|STATE  | NUMBER OF STORES | NUMBER OF TRANSACTIONS   | 
|-------|------------------|--------------------------|   
| ca    |   25             |        500               |
|-------|------------------|--------------------------| 
| il    |   2              |        25                |
|-------|------------------|--------------------------|
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698408/weighted-average-in-t-sql-like-excels-sumproduct

Comment: What is your number of transactions column? Is it a total for all stores in the state? What is the desired result for your example data?

Comment: yes the transactions column is a total of all orders/sales for stores in that state.  in the example i provided, among the 25 stores in california, there have been 500 sales.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted average in T-SQL (like Excel's SUMPRODUCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698408/weighted-average-in-t-sql-like-excels-sumproduct)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Just use

```
Sum(1.0 * [NUMBER OF TRANSACTIONS])/SUM([Number Of Stores])
```

Which gives 19.44 for your example data.

California has an average of 20 and Illinois 12.5 but California has 25 stores vs 2 so is weighted heavier.